# Load basefont from resource

Tags: c#, fonts, resources, itext

I'm trying to use ITextSharp and load a font file inserted in my project as resource.

I try different solutions but none of them seems to work, here a sample of what I did:

this one cannot load the resource

```
  private static BaseFont _bfArial;
    public static BaseFont BfArial
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bfArial == null)
                _bfArial = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"Resources\Images\arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            return _bfArial;
        }
    }
```

this one gives me an error: "'Identity-H' is not a supported encoding name."

```
 private static BaseFont _bfCourier;
    public static BaseFont BfCourier
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bfCourier == null)
                _bfCourier = BaseFont.CreateFont("Courier", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, FontsResources.cour, null);

            return _bfCourier;
        }
    }
```

and here the way I add the files in my solution

[image]

Can you please help me solving this issue? thank you

Andrea

Comment: The "encoding" `IDENTITY_H` can't be used for "Courier", so that error message is normal. However: you say you look for arialuni.ttf in the folder "Resources/Images", but when I look at your resources, I don't see a folder named "Images".

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
Byte[] fb = Properties.Resources.arialuni;
_bfArial = BaseFont.CreateFont("arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, BaseFont.CACHED, fb, null);
```

"Properties" appear under "GIGPrinting" in the Solution Explorer and "Properties.Resources" is the reference to the resources folder.